# HtmlEncode data from a webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, html-encode

I've created a simple web service for use with the ajax autocompleteextender control.  It works great, I'm almost done except there is one thing bothering me. When there is data in the database that is using html characters, the output data is un-friendly to a user.  For example "Test ;amp Test".  So when you start to type "Test" in the search box one of the results displayed is "Test ;amp Test".  I would like for it to instead be displayed as Test & Test without changing the data in the table.  I'm not sure exactly how to do this.

I have tried to htmlencode the string items but always get build errors.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Here is the guts of my webservice:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetActiveProducts(string prefixText)
        {

        ddconnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;Connect Timeout=200;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***;");
        ddconnection.Open();


         int count = 10;
         string sql = "SELECT TOP 10 title FROM Product WHERE active = '1' AND title LIKE @prefixText";
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ddconnection);
         da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 60).Value = "%" + prefixText + "%"; 
         DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
         da.Fill(dt); 
         string[] items = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
         int i = 0; 
         foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) 
         { 
          items.SetValue(dr["title"].ToString(),i); 
          i++;
         } 
         return items;
        }
```

Example of behavior.  (sorry to have to blur)

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Show us what you tried, and show the compiler error.

Comment: Pretty sure `;amp` isn't going to cause any problems... but: is the data stored unencoded (`a & b`) or encoded (`a &amp; b`)?

Comment: some of the data is stored encoded and some is stored unencoded.

Comment: `string Encoded = Server.HtmlEncode(items);
             return Encoded;`

Comment: `Error 334 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'`

Answer (score 0):

`Items` is an *array* of `string`s and `HtmlEncode` takes a `string`. That's why you are getting the build error. If you Encode the individual items separately, does it solve your problem?

EDIT: If you do `items.SetValue(Server.HtmlEncode(dr["title"].ToString()),i)` I guess you should at least get the encoding to work

Comment: What's the best way to achieve this?  Like `Server.HtmlEncode(items.SetValue(dr["title"].ToString(),i));`  ???